# is there a redundant inheritance in my style.xml?

Tags: android, inheritance, styles

I have this android style:

```
<resources>   <style name="TextAppearance.A.B.Base" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>   </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.A.B" parent="TextAppearance.A.B.Base"/>

  <style name="TextAppearance.A.B.C" parent="TextAppearance.A.B">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/google_sans_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
```

Why is the middleman needed?

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.A.B" parent="TextAppearance.A.B.Base"/>
```

couldn't it just be:

```
    <resources>   <style name="TextAppearance.A.B.Base" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>   </style>

      <style name="TextAppearance.A.B.C" parent="TextAppearance.A.B.Base">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/google_sans_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

I see it in an existing code and wasn't sure why is this item needed.

Also there is `namespace inheritance` vs `explicit inheritance`?

so this would also work?

```
    <resources>   <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.A.B.Base">
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>   </style>

      <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.A.B.Base">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/google_sans_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

`parent` attribute is just for making the namespace not too long?

Comment: middlemen may serve as a common point for a different style for overridden styles in different API level. We can add the code directly to middlemen which will be common to all it's children

Comment: please see my line:`couldn't it just be:`

in that case one cannot inherit from implicitly exist `TextAppearance.A.B` ?